# Psycopg2 on synology

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to run a script on synology DS116 which contains psycopg2. The program is written in Python 3.7.

When installing psycopg2, it gives an error:

> Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
> or specify the full executable path with the option:
>
> ```
> python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
> ```
>
> or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

How can I fix this error if I cannot install libpq-dev using apt-get, because I am using Synology?

Answer (score 0):

Use the version of psycopg2 that does not require a build system on the user end:

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi

"
psycopg2 is also available on PyPI in the form of wheel packages for the most common platform (Linux, OSX, Windows): this should make you able to install a binary version of the module, not requiring the above build or runtime prerequisites."

So:

`pip install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: I'm trying to install psycopg2 in this way ```pip install psycopg2-binary```` but have same error anyway
I don't have any ideas how to solve this problem

Comment: Are you running just ```pip install psycopg2-binary``` or are you also running the script you mentioned earlier?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is ```psycopg2-binary``` does not use setup.py to build itself on your machine, so installing it will not show the error message above. Something else is throwing that error.

Comment: has anyone found a solution? I'm getting the same error when using `pip install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: @user3691191. Create a new question with the following information; OS and version, Python version and psycopg2 version.